# Turn off discrete graphics card in a desktop PC

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

Is it possible to programmatically turn off the discrete graphics card in a PCI-e slot? Does turning off the graphics card in BIOS or Device Manager actually turn off power to the card? Example setups are two discrete graphics cards in two PCI-e slots, or a single discrete graphics card and an IGP.

Comment: It will disable operating system access to the card. It will almost certainly **not** power down the card. If you wish to save power then you should physically remove the card. Graphics cards move to a low power state when not doing demanding tasks and for a modern high performance card this should be less than 20W, by disabling the card you will simply leave the card unused but in its lower power state.

Comment: On some laptops it can be switched off in favor of the IGP for power saving. It seems strange that the power controller can turn off power to individual HDDs, NIC or USB ports, but not to a PCI-e slot. Even downclocked discrete card with 2-4GB GDDR5 and 5 billion transistors will consume much more power than the integrated card.

Comment: On  a laptop with dedicated driver and hardware support for GPU load handover and power management, along with a video management engine that takes frames from the dGPU and pipes it back at the iGPU display path. That is **extra** hardware and software instead of a lack of software and hardware control which is what you get when you just "disable" it. If you want to save power then you need to petition the manufacturers to bring this kind of hardware to desktops (unlikely to happen) or simply remove the card.